# How To Match Not Related Tables in Django

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-queryset

I have two tables which are not related-

```
class DedupeDataModel(models.Model):
    clean_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class SalesforceDataModel(models.Model):
    clean_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    salesforce_id = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I want to match the **clean_name** column in both the tables to get the **salesforce_ids** from **SalesforceDataModel** table. I have tried **select_related** to match the tables but since they are not related i am not getting results. Please give suggestions. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you query them like below?

```
matching_salesforce_ids=[]
for each in DedupeDataModel.objects.all():
   models=SalesforceDataModel.objects.filter(clean_name=each.clean_name)
   if len(models)>0:
     matching_salesforce_ids.append(models.first().salesforce_id)
```

Im assuming you have one SalesforceDataModel for each clean_name.

--EDIT---

You can also try this

```
clean_names=DedupeDataModel.objects.all().values('clean_name')
salesforceids=SalesforceDataModel.objects.filter(clean_name__in=clean_names).values('salesforce_id')
```

Sorry, I dont know why I havent thought about this one before!

Comment: I have nearly 100k rows in each table, so it wont be very efficient method i guess.. anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: I just edited my answer, please see if that works for you! Values makes everything much faster!